# mysql joins and groups

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I'm new to this forum from the standpoint of posting, as this question may show. I'm having some issues with the way I want my data to appear.

So, I have 3 tables (I am only showing the columns that I want):

visitors:

```
center_id (where the visitor was)  |  state_id (where they came from)
```

centers:

```
center_id  |  center
```

states:

```
state_id  |  state
```

here is the query that I have been using

```
SELECT states.state, visitors.center_id, visitors.state_id, centers.center, COUNT(visitors.state_id) AS totalCount 
FROM visitors 
LEFT JOIN states ON states.state_id = visitors.state_id 
LEFT JOIN centers ON centers.center_id = visitors.center_id 
WHERE visitors.vdate = <some date> AND visitors.state_id <> '0'  
GROUP BY centers.center, visitors.state_id
```

This produces the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [state] => Connecticut
            [location_id] => 1
            [state_id] => 8
            [center] => Little River
            [totalCount] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [state] => California
            [location_id] => 5
            [state_id] => 6
            [center] => North Augusta
            [totalCount] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [state] => Colorado
            [location_id] => 5
            [state_id] => 7
            [center] => North Augusta
            [totalCount] => 2
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [state] => Connecticut
            [location_id] => 9
            [state_id] => 8
            [center] => Santee
            [totalCount] => 2
        )

     [7] => Array
        (
            [state] => Virginia 
            [location_id] => 9
            [state_id] => 51
            [center] => Santee
            [totalCount] => 1
        )
)
```

This is what I really want:

```
Array
(
    [Little River] => Array
        (
          [0] => Array
             (
                [state] => Connecticut
                [state_id] => 8
                [totalCount] => 1
             )
        )

    [North Augusta] => Array
        (
           [0] => Array
              (
                [state] => California
                [state_id] => 6
                [totalCount] => 1
              )

           [1] => Array
              (
                [state] => Colorado
                [state_id] => 7
                [totalCount] => 2
              )
          )
      [Santee] => Array
          (
           [0] => Array
              (
                [state] => Connecticut
                [state_id] => 8
                [totalCount] => 2
              )

           [1] => Array
              (
                [state] => Virginia 
                [state_id] => 51
                [totalCount] => 1
              )
          )
)
```

Ultimately I'm putting this into a table that looks something like this:

```
__________________
|State   |   Count|
-------------------
|     Santee      |
-------------------
| Georgia |   5   |
-------------------
| Alabama |   10  |
-------------------
| North Augusta   |
-------------------
| another |    7  |
-------------------
```

Sorry for being long winded, but this was the only way that I could describe it.

I've also tried breaking it out in php, but I'm probably doing something wrong there too. I can make a table with 3 columns with the center listed with each state, but I'm realliy looking for  a row that show the center followed by all of the states and counts for that center and on to the next center.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you fetching the results in php?

Answer (score 0):

A query may only return a two- (or less) dimentional result. You will need to parse this result set to transform it into a tree.

With PHP, there really is no difficulty:

```
foreach ($rawResultSet as $row) {
    $finalResult[$row['center']][] = array(
        $row['state'],
        $row['state_id'],
        $row['totalCount']

    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did find what I was looking for and it was very close to what you recommended. Then it was a matter of using nested foreach loops. Sorry, I would have 1+ it, but I don't have enough reputation.